# Certificate problem while cloning a https url with git

Tags: git, curl

I have git version 1.7.2.2 and curl 7.21.1 on my MacOS. I'm trying to clone an url like:

```
git clone https:// repositories.mydomain.com/myproject/myproject.git myproject
```

but getting,

> error: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?) while accessing https://repositories.mydomain.com/myproject/myproject.git/info/refs

I tried

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

to ignore SSL but that didn't work. I also put CA cert into /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt but that didn't work also.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the culprit

there was a environment variable named GIT_SSL_CERT which was pointing out to a jks. so it was overriding all my configs.

Answer (score 1):

To use an alternate certificate file on Git:

```
git config --global http.sslcainfo latest/ca/path
```

To obtain an alternate certificate file, refer to: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and get cacert.pem file.